# Attribute Error for strings created from lists

Tags: regex, list, web-scraping, attributes

I'm trying to create a data-scraping file for a class, and the data I have to scrape requires that I use while loops to get the right data into separate arrays-- i.e. for states, and SAT averages, etc.

However, once I set up the while loops, my regex that cleared the majority of the html tags from the data broke, and I am getting an error that reads:

> Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

My Code is:

```
import re, util
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

# create a comma-delineated file
delim = ", "

#base url for sat data
base = "http://www.usatoday.com/news/education/2007-08-28-sat-table_N.htm"

#get webpage object for site
soup = util.mysoupopen(base)

#get column headings
colCols = soup.findAll("td", {"class":"vaTextBold"})

#get data
dataCols = soup.findAll("td", {"class":"vaText"})

#append data to cols
for i in range(len(dataCols)):
    colCols.append(dataCols[i])

#open a csv file to write the data to
fob=open("sat.csv", 'a')

#initiate the 5 arrays
states = []
participate = []
math = []
read = []
write = []

#split into 5 lists for each row
for i in range(len(colCols)):
    if i%5 == 0:
        states.append(colCols[i])
i=1
while i<=250:
    participate.append(colCols[i])
    i = i+5

i=2
while i<=250:
    math.append(colCols[i])
    i = i+5

i=3
while i<=250:
    read.append(colCols[i])
    i = i+5

i=4
while i<=250:
    write.append(colCols[i])
    i = i+5

#write data to the file
for i in range(len(states)):
    states = str(states[i])
    participate = str(participate[i])
    math = str(math[i])
    read = str(read[i])
    write = str(write[i])

    #regex to remove html from data scraped

    #remove <td> tags
    line = re.search(">(.*)<", states).groups()[0] + delim + re.search(">(.*)<",       participate).groups()[0]+ delim  + re.search(">(.*)<", math).groups()[0] + delim + re.search(">(.*)<", read).groups()[0] + delim  + re.search(">(.*)<", write).groups()[0]

    #append data point to the file
   fob.write(line)
```

Any ideas regarding why this error suddenly appeared? The regex was working fine until I tried to split the data into different lists. I have already tried printing the various strings inside the final "for" loop to see if any of them were "None" for the first i value (0), but they were all the string that they were supposed to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the regex search is failing on (one of) the strings, so it returns `None` instead of a `MatchObject`.

Try the following instead of the very long `#remove <td> tags` line:

```
out_list = []
for item in (states, participate, math, read, write):
    try:
        out_list.append(re.search(">(.*)<", item).groups()[0])
    except AttributeError:
        print "Regex match failed on", item
        sys.exit()
line = delim.join(out_list)
```

That way, you can find out where your regex is failing.

Also, I suggest you use `.group(1)` instead of `.groups()[0]`. The former is more explicit.